# Python if-elif-else expressions returning a value and scope resolution

Tags: python

**Question 1**

In rust, I can write code like this:

```
let foo = if ... {
  1
} else if ... {
  2
} else {
  3
};
```

Here foo is assigned the return value of that if-elseif-else expression.

Is something similar possible in Python?

**Question 2**

Is the outer variable "foo" updated in this python code?

```
foo = "hello"

if cond1:
   foo = "world"
else:
   pass

# if cond1 is true, what is the value of foo now? "hello" or "world"
```

Comment: Use `print(foo)`?

Comment: What about Question 1 ?

Comment: `else: pass` is useless - you can remove it.

Comment: python has `foo = 1 if ... else (2 if ... else 3)`  but it is less readable then normal `if/else`

Answer (score 1):

it seems the closest Py version is a ternary op

```
#scenario 2

foo = "hello"

foo = "world" if True else foo

print(foo) # prints 'world'
```